# JMeter: Sampler for JMX/MBeans?

Tags: jmeter, jmx, mbeans

I there a possibility to access MBeans of the system under test from JMeter? I have a system which has several deployments, but needs a MBean call to do final initialization and startup. I need to access and run this. Addtionally, it would be great to get some information out off MBeans for testing.

How is this possible? Do I really need to write an own sampler?

Comment: Sorry I'm not experienced with jmeter.  We had to roll your own.  My JMX package might help if you decide to do so as well: http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To init your component you could use à jmeter setup thread group and use a jsr223 sampler using groovy as underlying package.

With groovy it's very easy to call jmx operations:

- http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+and+JMX

Otherwise there is a plugin:

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-rest-sampler/

It contains a jmx sampler in it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a project with a set of plugins for JMeter one of which supports JMX: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMonMetrics#JMX_Metrics

Comment: It only supports 3 different metrics.

Answer (score 1):

The PerfMon mentioned above by mvmn will access MBeans of the system under test, but the preferred JMeter Plugin solution is to use the new JMX-specific plugin.

The following link shows how to identify a jmx metric in JConsole MBean tree (using ObjectName, attribute name, etc..) and then add that info to the JMXMon interface.

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/